# iPhone/iPad App with an Animated Splashscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, splash-screen

I am looking for a way to animate the Splashscreen of an iOS App. I googled a lot but all that I found were just pseudo-solutions, that add a screen AFTER the application was loaded (`applicationDidFinishLoading:`). For me this seems not to be a suitable solution because the user has to wait additional seconds. That's, in my opinion, not the purpose of a splash screen - to increase the loading time.

So what I am looking for is: Is there a way to really animate the splash screen without increasing the loading time? I am thinking of just a small rotating circle while the app is launching.

I guess the answer is no... :-/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed , the answer is no. If you don't do anything in `applicationDidFinishLaunching: withOptions:` and only go to the first pseudo screen like you saw in other places it will only take like 0.5 seconds until that screen is displayed. That is however your only option. And it's not bad.

Comment: Yes the answer is no. Please close your question now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html) strongly suggests opening the app as quickly as possible, which means no splash screens:

> **Avoid displaying an About window or a splash screen.** In general, try
>   to avoid providing any type of startup experience that prevents people
>   from using your application immediately.

Apple intends for you to use a static image that makes it look like your app is instantly ready when opened. Therefore, if you really want animation, you have to wait for `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Answer (score 1):

No. The splash HAS to be a PNG image and PNG images cannot be animated. I think you used to be able to use JPG images but same story there.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "No. That's not possible because the 'splash screen' has to be a PNG image." However, I wonder how long the app is taking to launch? The Default.png splash screen goes away whenever you are able to add a subview to your application, which is typically done in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method. If you're doing a lot of set up in that method before you actually hook into it to start your view chain, there is an opportunity here to use the same method described by @George in the comments.

You can add a subview that is the default image as a background with an activity indicator. Then, do all your app set up (if you're retrieving data from the Internet for example) and when that set up is done and/or data has finished loading, remove that subview and display your main view like you normally would.

So, no you can't animate the Default.png splash screen when an app launches, but if you're doing a lot of set up in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, add a subview before that set up which gives some feedback to user and then execute the code that takes a while.

***EDIT***

I should note that it doesn't HAVE to be a PNG file, but there is no difference in terms of your question with regards to animating. I'm mostly talking about convention when I say "Default.png" file.